How can I train a TimeGAN model from Synthcity package without outcome variable?
For a multi timeseries dataset, I am using TimeGAN from synthcity package to generate a synthetic version. Before fitting the data to the model, the data must be converted to a DataLoader. This DataLoader requires four input arguments, temporal_data, observation_times, static_data and outcome. However, my dataset does not contain an outcome feature. So if I run these lines of code:
# instantiate time series data loader
loader = TimeSeriesDataLoader(
    temporal_data=temporal_dataframes,
    observation_times=observation_data,
    static_data=static_data
)
plugin_params = dict(
            n_iter = 20,
            batch_size = 100,
            lr = 0.001,
            generator_n_layers_hidden = 2,
            generator_n_units_hidden = 2,
            discriminator_n_layers_hidden = 2,
            discriminator_n_units_hidden = 2
        )
syn_model = Plugins().get("timegan", **plugin_params)

syn_model.fit(loader)

I get the following error:

So, how can I train the TimeGAN model without defining an outcome feature?
